# Firebase query for data within a date range

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase data looks like this:

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "vacationDates" : "2016-12-20 - 2016-12-25",
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "vacationDates" : "2016-12-10 - 2016-12-20",
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
}
```

How do i query for all dinosaurs that will be away on vacation on 2016-12-20 (i.e it should return both lambeosaurus and stegosaurus)? Or should I actually store the data differently? If so, how should I store the data for optimum performance? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Combining the two dates doesn't do much in terms of making the database easier to query.

If you are searching for dinosaurs on holiday on a particular date, they could have gone on holiday anytime before that date. (Unless there is a policy that mandates a maximum number of days in a holiday.) So the end date is probably what you want to query:

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "vacationStart" : "2016-12-20",
    "vacationEnd" : "2016-12-25",
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "vacationStart" : "2016-12-10",
    "vacationEnd" : "2016-12-20",
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
}
```

Any dinosaurs with a `vacationEnd` on or after `2016-12-20` will be on holiday on that date if `vacationStart` is on or before `2016-12-20`:

```js
function getHolidayingDinosaurs(day) {
  return firebase.database()
    .ref("dinousaurs")
    .orderByChild("vacationEnd")
    .startAt(day)
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let holidaying = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        let val = child.val();
        if (val.vacationStart <= day) {
          holidaying.push(val);
        }
      });
      return holidaying;
    });
}

getHolidayingDinosaurs("2016-12-20").then((holidaying) => console.log(holidaying));
```

There isn't a straight-forward alternative to performing further filtering on the client, as you can only query Firebase using a single property and the combined dates aren't particularly useful as the start and end could be any dates on or before/after the query date.

Anyway, querying using `vacationEnd` is likely to perform most of the filtering on the server - unless you have a lot of dinosaurs that plan their holidays well in advance.

If the above approach results in too much information being retrieved and filtered on the client, you could put in some extra effort and could maintain your own mapping of holidaying dinosaurs by storing some additional data structured like this:

```
"holidays": {
  ...
  "2016-12-19": {
    "stegosaurus": true
  },
  "2016-12-20": {
    "lambeosaurus": true,
    "stegosaurus": true
  },
  "2016-12-21": {
    "lambeosaurus": true
  },
  ...
}
```

Firebase's multi-location updates can be used to make maintaining the mapping a little easier (there are more multi-location examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41173428/6680611)):

```
firebase.database().ref().update.({
  "dinosaurs/lambeosaurus": {
    "vacationStart" : "2016-12-20",
    "vacationEnd" : "2016-12-25",
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "holidays/2016-12-20/lambeosaurus": true,
  "holidays/2016-12-21/lambeosaurus": true,
  "holidays/2016-12-22/lambeosaurus": true,
  "holidays/2016-12-23/lambeosaurus": true,
  "holidays/2016-12-24/lambeosaurus": true,
  "holidays/2016-12-25/lambeosaurus": true
});
```

A query on `holidays/2016-12-20` would then return an object with keys for each holidaying dinosaur.

Comment: With update() is it possible to get firebase to generate a unique id like push()? for example, the data should really look like this {
  "lambeosaurus": {
    firebaseUniqueId: {
    "vacationStart" : "2016-12-20",
    "vacationEnd" : "2016-12-25",
    },
firebaseUniqueId-2: {
    "vacationStart" : "2017-01-21",
    "vacationEnd" : "2017-01-25",
    },
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    firebaseUniqueId-3: {
    "vacationStart" : "2016-12-10",
    "vacationEnd" : "2016-12-20",
   }
}
}

Comment: No, but the IDs are generated on the client and it's easy to generate one. This will generate a key that you can use in a path within an `update` call: `let key = firebase.database().ref().push().key` (Note that doing so won't touch the database; it all happens on the client.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing the data in a different way. Use one attribute for "vacationStart" and one for "vacationEnd". And also, put all the dinosaurs inside a "dinousaurs" node, and not in the root node.

So in order to query for all dinosaurs that will be away on vacation on 2016-12-20, you would use the query:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('dinousaurs').orderByChild('vacationStart').equalTo('2016-12-20');
```