# Querying Firebase Database to get a filtered list

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So basically I am using Vuejs and have a Firebase Database which has holidays{}.
Inside holidays it has 
`{title:'example 1', start:'2018-01-01', end:'2018-01-05'}
{title:'example 2', start:'2018-01-05', end:'2018-01-09'}`

I then want to pass a date '2018-01-03'. The query should check if this date is on or between the 'start or 'end' and give me back all the objects which are.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately this is a tricky scenario. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381948/firebase-query-for-data-within-a-date-range for a previous suggestion.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the response. I took a look at that previously but didnt make much sense to me.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the only solution offered to the same question in the past. As I said: it's a tricky scenario.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No problem. Ill have another look to see if i can wrap my head around it and implement. Thanks for your time